# Is this expectation known?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, logarithm

I'm wondering whether the following expectation has a known form:
$$\text{E}_{\beta}\left\{ \log \Phi(x^T \beta)\right\},$$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution function, $x$ is a fixed vector ($p \times 1$) and $\beta$ is a ($p \times 1$) random vector such that $\beta_j \overset{ind}\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_j, \sigma_j^2)$, $j = 1, \ldots, p$.

Likewise, I would need to compute $\text{E}_{\beta}\left[ \log\left\{1 - \Phi(X \beta)\right\}\right]$.

Have these expectation a known form? I known for instance that $\text{E}\left\{ \log X\right\}$ can be expressed in terms of the digamma function is $X$ is a Beta or a Gamma random variable. It would be great to have something similar here...

Comment: Clarification: $X$ is $1 \times p$ and $\beta$ is $p \times 1$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I did not mention this.

Comment: Your notation is difficult to decipher: evidently $\Phi$ is a real-valued function of a real *vector*, but exactly what is it?

Comment: $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution function. Sorry about the notation, I've updated the question (hopefully better now...).

Comment: ? marginal of $X\beta$ is not standard normal, so $\Phi(X\beta)$ is not uniform.